# Is the iPhone5 and up not Network locked?

Tags: network, iphone, sim, cellular-carriers

In my experience phones have been [locked to the carrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIM_lock), requiring a hefty fee and a contract payout to transfer them to another carrier. (Just because they can).

This [commentator writes](https://twitter.com/michaelneale/status/537461433249062912):

> Oh all iphone 5 and up are not sim/network locked (didn’t know that)

My question is: **Is the iPhone5 and up not Network locked?**

(I'm aware that A[pple has patents for future Sim-less phones](http://www.patentlyapple.com/patently-apple/2011/11/apple-introduces-us-to-the-virtual-sim-card.html) that will further obviate this problem).

Comment: "just because they can" is not the reason and a sim-less phone won't solve the "problem".  (CDMA carriers such as verizon don't even use SIMs, yet their phones are still carrier locked.)

Comment: Thanks- that's helpful. The phrase 'just because they can' was meant to imply that sim-locking has no obvious benefits to the consumer, but as a feature of the SIMs has commercial benefits to the carrier to the disadvantage of the consumer. Carriers seem rarely able to summon the force of will to resist this temptation but now it seems consumer sentiment and branding is requiring this goodwill.

Comment: Think of the carrier lock as a mortgage on your phone.  The carrier subsidizes the purchase of your phone, essentially adding money to what you put down.  All they ask for that in return is that you stay a customer for X-period of time.  To make sure that you keep your promise they make it so you can't use the phone on another carriers network until you have done what you promised when they helped you buy it.  Don't want the carrier lock? that's fine just pay full prices for the phone, not the carriers subsidized price.

Comment: Thanks Tyson - that's helpful. My experience is that the carrier will leave the phone locked even after you have paid off the contract.

Comment: True. Unless you request that it be unlocked.  This time the reason really is "because they can".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All iPhone models are offered with and without a carrier lock, also 4, 4s (which I write this from, I never bought or will buy a locked one) and the newer ones. In Europe it is a must to offer unlocked versions, I don't know about the policy in the country you live. The lock is on demand of the carrier, not of Apple.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true. iPhones can still be network-locked.

See this Apple KB article for information on unlocking iPhones, demonstrating that they are still able to be locked:

- http://support.apple.com/HT201328